# find pattern in the following sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, summation

I would like to represent the following with a simple function.
the pattern is this
$1,3,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,\dots,n$

Note all the numbers with an integer result for a logarithm with base 2 are not present in the series ($2,4,8,16,\ldots$ etc are not present in the series).

Can you help me find a pattern and represent the summation with a simple function.

Thanks

Comment: I am unable to figure out yet but will let you know if it works..can you write me your answer in plain english because the code hasn't been interpreted by the site.

Comment: $$f(n)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \log_2(n)\rfloor}2^k \right)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor}2^k\right)$$
 
I'm not sure whether the latter sum can be simplified further. Is this sufficient enough for you?

Comment: I have edited the comment. Does it appear clearly now?

Comment: Great work...thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is sums of two or more consecutive nonnegative integers.

http://oeis.org/A138591